# Google Cloud keep executing program vm instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to execute a program in a vm instance in Google Cloud without having an active session? For example, every time I execute a program, it stops executing once I end my ssh connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run it in the background using the nohup tool

`nohup ./yourscript &`

For Documentation on uses,

http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/nohup-invocation.html#nohup-invocation